# Do not pass $this into scope of an anonymous function

Tags: php

Is there a way to not pass the class into an anonymous function?

```
class Foo{

  public function bar(){
     $data = [
        'calculation' => function(){
           // I don't want $this to be passed into here
        }
     ];
  }
}
```

Can i exclude $this from that anonymous function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want a value for `$this`, you want a [static anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous-functions.static).

```
class Foo{
  public function bar(){
     $data = [
        'calculation' => static function(){
           // $this is not defined
        }
     ];
  }
}
```

Static anonymous functions do not have a `$this` value automatically bound and they cannot have another value bound to them later on.